# matTooltip doesn't work properly with translate pipe | Angular 11

Tags: angular, angular-material

I've stumbled upon an issue with matTooltip usage. Let's imagine I have something like:

```
<div matTooltip="{{ 'statuses.' + status | translate }}"
     [matTooltipDisabled]="hideTooltip"
     (mouseenter)="isTruncated($event)">
     <span>{{ 'statuses.' + status | translate }}</span> <!-- translation works properly -->
</div>
```

Where `status` is taken from the template. This is how `hideTooltip` is assigned/calculated:

```
isTruncated(event: any) {
    this.hideTooltip = this.helpers.isNotTruncated(event);  
}
---
// inside helpersService

isNotTruncated(event: any): boolean {
    if (event.target) {
      if (event.target.scrollWidth && event.target.offsetWidth) {
        return !(event.target.scrollWidth > event.target.offsetWidth);
      } else if (event.target.scrollWidth === 0) {
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
```

So, actual result is: when value is in english (default language) and it's truncated, matTooltip is shown on mouse hover. But the problem appears when changing language. When value is in polish (just an example, it doesn't depend on a concrete language), matTooltip is always hidden and scrollWidth always equals offsetWidth. Does anybody know the solution? Or is it an inner material/translate pipe issue?

Comment: Is that built-in Angular i18n? Or some custom translation module / external library? Anyway, my first guess would be that the pipe might work asynchronously when it needs translation and this means that isTruncated is called before actual text is rendered into your div - hence it will not show the tooltip.

Comment: @TotallyNewb i18n is used, yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting this answer in case somebody will find this useful.
The problem was related to the length of translated phrases. When the value is small, it was not truncated properly.
So the solution was simple:

```
template
--------
<div matTooltip="{{ 'statuses.' + status | translate }}"
     [matTooltipDisabled]="hideTooltip"
     class="status-truncated"
     (mouseenter)="isTruncated($event)">
     <span>{{ 'statuses.' + status | translate }}</span>
</div>
------
------
styles
------
.status-truncated {
  letter-spacing: .2px;
}
```